# vsftpd does not allow chrooted users write to directory

Tags: ftp, chroot, vsftp

I installed vsftpd on ubuntu 12.04 and chrooted local users, in order not to let them see the other parts of system. but when a local user wants to login into ftp it gives out this error:

```
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
```

Why is this happening? And what is the problem to let the chrooted users to write into the directory?

Do I have to compile my vsftp with extra arguments? Why aren't the included in the main package?

Answer (score 2):

Allowing a writable root directory may be less secure than intended, though it's not necessarily a show-stopper. Therefore many builds allow you to turn off this security feature. Whether this is allowed, and whether the configuration option is misspelled depends on your particular build. But one of these two should work:

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES

allow_writable_chroot=YES
```

Comment: what is security problem of this?

Comment: @HojatTaheri it's a root escape. http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2009-May/027651.html