# SFTP server without root as owner of the user's folder?

Tags: sftp, vsftpd

I installed a SFTP server with [SSH](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot). But the chroot directory must be owned by root, then the user can't write on it.

Is there any way to allow that user to write in its root directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the vsftpd conf file check for:

allow_writable_chroot=YES

LINK TO MY ANSWER:

[vsftpd does not allow chrooted users write to directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106389/vsftpd-does-not-allow-chrooted-users-write-to-directory)

Comment: Despite 'sftp' in its name, `vsftpd` is not an SFTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you create two folders (could be "in" and "out" or whatever you want) and allow access to those folders, that way the user can't write in / but can write in those folders.